# Negligible presence of Spider-Man in Captain America: Civil War posters, trailers, etc

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, captain-america-civil-war, marketing

Spider-Man had a key role in *Captain America: Civil War*. But he wasn't  present in any posters or film pics or trailers released by Marvel. Can anybody tell the reason?

Comment: Flawed premise. He was in at least two major trailers.

Comment: https://youtu.be/QGfhS1hfTWw?t=2m11s

Comment: I'd say to keep the element of surprise, like its appearance in the trailer, just at the end.

Comment: “Spider-Man had a key role in Captain America: Civil War.” Debatable. I loved his appearance, but remove it and I don’t think the movie changes much.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Marvel did not have full unadulterated control over Spider-Man. Spider-Man is still under Sony control, so Sony would have major veto power over any instance of Spidey in marketing. To avoid any issue, and to inflate the "special guest star" factor for him, they avoided using him in all (meaning every piece of) marketing.

Comment: He was in traielrs and the premises of the question is even wrong.